# A Diophantine rational function

Tags: mathematics

For how many integers $N$ is the rational function $\frac{N^2-2N-15}{N^2-N-12}$ also an integer?

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. The "obvious" way to approach this would be to write $N^2−2N−15=M(N^2−N−12)$ and then try to reduce possibilities for $M$ and $N$, perhaps by using modular arithmetic or even brute-forcing. The "aha moment" required by the [linked policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/5373) is to factorise the polynomials, and the "unexpected result" is that only two values of $N$ work and it's easy to find which ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the given expression can be simplified to

> $\frac{(N-5)(N+3)}{(N-4)(N+3)}=\frac{N-5}{N-4}=1-\frac{1}{N-4}$,

we simply need to make sure

> $N-4$ divides $1$, i.e., $N-4=\pm 1$, which leads to $N=5$ or $N=3$. We can check that both of them work.

So

> There are two such $N$.

Comment: Perfect! I was hoping to lead people on a wild goose chase with $N^2-2N-15=M(N^2-N-12)$ or suchlike, but you're too good.